# JSF 2.0 f:ajax submission java.lang.IllegalStateException error: Parameters processing failed

Tags: jsf

I developing web application with JBOSS AS-7.1.1 Final, and Seam 3.1.0 Final. I just beginning working, but struck with following problem:
I have a submission button with following code:

```
    <h:commandButton action="#{projectController.create}" value="Create Project" styleClass="greyishBtn submitForm">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" event="click" render="tblObject"/>
    </h:commandButton>
```

When I click on button, following error occur:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException error: Parameters processing failed.
```

The action is not trigger, but if I remove the  tag, everything works fine, just non-ajax.

Here is the backend code:

```
    @Named
@RequestScoped
@Model
public class ProjectController implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3572096930093985831L;

@Inject private EntityManager em;
@Inject private Logger log;
//@Inject private FacesContext facesContext;
@Inject private Event<Project> projectEventSrc;

private String projectId;

@Produces
@Named
private Project project;

private Query query;

private List<Project> projectList;
private List<ProjectDTO> projectDtoList;



public ProjectController() {
    // Default constructor.
}

@PostConstruct
public void postInit(){
    // Init project
    project = new Project();

    // Get project list.
    query = em.createQuery("select project from Project project");
    projectList = query.getResultList();
    projectDtoList = new ArrayList<ProjectDTO>();

    for(Project project : projectList){
        ProjectDTO projectDTO = new ProjectDTO();
        projectDTO.setProjectId(project.getProjectId());
        projectDTO.setProjectName(project.getProjectName());
        projectDTO.setProjectStatus(23.4d);
        // Add to list.
        projectDtoList.add(projectDTO);
    }

}

public void loadProject(){
    // Load project here based on project id.
    if(projectId == null){
        // Do nothing.
        return;
    }

    // Load from DB.
    project = em.find(Project.class, projectId);
}

/**
 * Create new project.
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void create() throws Exception{
    log.info("Creating: " + project.getProjectName());
    project.setProjectId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    em.persist(project);
    //facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Registered!", "Registration successful"));
    projectEventSrc.fire(project);

    // Reinit.
    project = new Project();
}

public void setProjectId(String projectId) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
}

public String getProjectId(){
    return this.projectId;
}


public List<Project> getProjectList() {
    return projectList;
}

public void setProjectList(List<Project> projectList) {
    this.projectList = projectList;
}

public List<ProjectDTO> getProjectDtoList() {
    return projectDtoList;
}

public void setProjectDtoList(List<ProjectDTO> projectDtoList) {
    this.projectDtoList = projectDtoList;
}
```

}

anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in JBoss AS 7.1.1 and occurs only when IE browser is been used. See also issue [AS7-5143](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5143).

As of now, the only solution seems to be to downgrade to JBoss AS 7.1.0.

Comment: Thanks, BalusC, I don't have IE on my machine (MAC), it happened on Chrome as well.

Comment: The bug report mentioned that it failed in IE and succeeded in Firefox. No wording about Chrome. The bug reporter apparently didn't bother to test it in other popular browsers.

Comment: I just added a comment in the bug to mention that it also doesn't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as a work around, if you are happy to include a 3rd party library, you can use PrimeFaces commandButton instead.  It uses ajax by default and this appears to work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem occurred because there was one of my custom components being rendered without the attribute 'name'.
The problem was gone after I include the attribute on the encoding method.
jboss. 7.1.1/jsf 2.1.10/Eclipse Juno